# TreeView control displays blank with checkboxes after windows 10 update

Tags: c, windows-10, activex

I have a problem with a Production application, The application is written in a framework called CA PLEX this is sort of a code generator.

Now the whole application is generated as WinC and we use windows active x controls for example the Treeview for explorers and the date control.

After windows updated the tree view for some reason is blank with checkbox like picture on all of the items in the tree view were the ext of the menu should be.

All worked fine before the windows 10 update... Does anyone know how to fix this? Is there a windows patch to fix this? Or a setting in windows to fix this?

On my laptop that is running Windows 10 64bit The application does this every morning when I open my laptop from sleep mode, then I have to restart my laptop and then the treeview is working again.

We had a new instance of the problem but restarting is not fixing it for them it keeps on setting the treeview like the image below.

The application is a 32bit WinC app.

How the tree grid looks like now :

[image]

The TreeView Component is :

[image]

And for reference I also asked the question on the CA PLEX forum :

https://communities.ca.com/message/242108048-treeview-control-displays-blank-with-checkboxes-after-windows-10-update

Comment: Before you vote to close the question, please tell me why?

Comment: I didn't vote anything but I am surprised that activeX is 1. used at all 2. for such things.

Comment: Jip its still used in allot of windows based applications.

Answer (score 0):

We updated to version 6.0 of the control and the issue seems to be resolved now.